# How much do holes in metal shrink when it is galvanized?

Tags: metal, steel, hole

I'm going to have some mild steel tubes with holes drilled on it hot-dipped galvanized. I need to know how much tolerance or how big the holes should be when I drill them so that they would be at least an inch in diameter after the galvanization process. Of course, I don't want the holes too big too afterwards.

I tried Googling the answer to this question but failed to see usable numbers. This is most probably because it depends on the size of the holes and the type of metal being galvanized. So if anyone can give some numbers based on their experience, that would help a lot.

Comment: Have you asked the vendor doing the galvanizing how thick the added material would be? They should be able to spec it out for you with your quote.

Comment: @mikes I think your comment is actually the answer.

Comment: I make it an answer for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vendor will be able to give you this information based on the thickness they apply the material and any specs you gave or requested when they quote the job.

Comment: You're right. I should probably just contact the galvanizing factory for this info.